Search data extension by non primary key
I've got a data extension with an Email non-primary key, and need to make an API call to find all records matching a given email address.
Looking through the documentation there's the REST call to retrieve data, but that specifically says:

$filter ... You can only filter on primary keys.

The only idea I've had is to change my primary key to include the email addresses somehow? Or am I missing a more suitable API call in the docs somewhere?
Can anyone point me where to look next?

If you really need to make an API call for this then you can make a custom API call. You can watch the tutorial here.
First, create a Code Resource page where the page type is JSON type.
Then, write a SSJS script for the Code Resource page to retrieve record rows with a filter based on the DE email field.
I put my sample code here so you can adjust it for your DE
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var jsonOut = {};
var recordRows = [];

try{
var email = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("email");

var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows("Your DE name", "Your email field name", email);
if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
    for(var i=0; i<dataRows.length; i++) {
        recordRows.push(dataRows[i]);;
    }
}

// Add attribute to JSON output
jsonOut["emailFilter"] = email;
jsonOut["recordCount"] = recordRows.length;
jsonOut["recordRows"] = recordRows;


Write(Stringify(jsonOut));

} catch(ex){
    Write(Stringify(ex));
}

</script>

Call request:
GET: https://YOUR_RESOURCE_PAGE_URL?email={Email to filter}
Content-Type: application/json


Thank you, this looks great - I didn't know this was possible.
I did find you can query the SOAP API by non-primary fields, so started down that road, but this looks like it may be a lot neater.
